# how to convert curl command to http request in flutter?

Tags: flutter, http, curl

how convert this command curl `$ curl -i --basic -u admin:public -X GET "http://localhost:8081/api/v4"`    to http method to use it in flutter

and the result:

`{"data":[{"path":"/auth_clientid","name":"list_clientid","method":"GET","descr":"List available clientid in the cluster"}, ...],"code":0}`

please help thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this website: https://curl.trillworks.com/#dart

To convert curl commands to dart http requests.

[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E19k2.png)

Comment: Thanks @Asjad for sharing this solution. It works like a charm.